# How to use two separate MongoDB databases in .NET Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, dependency-injection, worker

I have 2 MongoDB Databases and want to use in Worker Service class:

```cs
services.Configure<DbConnectSetting>(
    hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("fwkConfiguration:DataBase1Settings"))
    .AddTransient<IDbConnectSetting>(s =>
        s.GetRequiredService<IOptions<DbConnectSetting>>().Value)
    .AddTransient(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>))
    .AddTransient(typeof(IDB1Repository), typeof(DB1Repository));

services.Configure<DbConnectSetting>(
    hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("fwkConfiguration:DataBase2Setting"))
    .AddTransient<IDbConnectSetting>(s =>
        s.GetRequiredService<IOptions<DbConnectSetting>>().Value)
    .AddTransient(typeof(IRepository<>),typeof(Repository<>))
    .AddTransient(typeof(IDB2Repository), typeof(DB2Repository));
```

But the problem is it always takes the lastly create DB2 value for both the Instance of Object in worker class, is there anything to resolve to take seperate values.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give the options a name. [Check this docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.optionsconfigurationservicecollectionextensions.configure?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-optionsconfigurationservicecollectionextensions-configure-1(microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-iservicecollection-system-string-microsoft-extensions-configuration-iconfiguration))

Something like:

```
services.Configure<DbConnectSetting>("DB1" ,...);  
services.Configure<DbConnectSetting>("DB12 ,...);
// Usage
public Foo(IOptionsSnapshot<DbConnectSetting> options){
options.Get("DB1");
```